# opening multiple netcdf4 files into single array using xarray

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I am trying to read multiple files using xarray in python but getting the error
"**Could not find any dimension coordinates to use to order the datasets for concatenation**"

Here is my code

```
import xarray as xr

test = xr.open_mfdataset(['test1.nc4', 'test2.nc4'])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get the best result on Stack Overflow, see how to ask good questions [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be Minimal, Reproducible Example [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback).

Comment: Indeed, specifically it'd be helpful to see what the files look like when opened individually. i.e. `ds1 = xr.open_dataset('test1.nc4')` and then `print(ds1)`.

Comment: Also there's a `concat_dim` parameter in `open_mfdataset` which you can use if you need to concatenate the files along a dimension which doesn't already exist in one of the datasets. http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html